# How does the SQL injection from the "Bobby Tables" XKCD comic work?

Tags: security, validation, sql-injection

Just looking at:

[image: XKCD Strip]
*(Source: https://xkcd.com/327/)*

What does this SQL do:

```
Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --
```

I know both `'` and `--` are for comments, but doesn't the word `DROP` get commented as well since it is part of the same line?

Comment: If you listen to [Stack Overflow Podcast #31](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/podcast-31/) (November 27, 2008), they actually discuss this.

Comment: In MySQL, `'` is not for [comments](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comments.html). Even if it were, there is no space before it so it can only end the string that precedes it.

Comment: As far as XKCD goes, if there is any question about some of the comics you can always go to [Explain XKCD](http://www.explainxkcd.com/) and have your answer figured out. There is even a [XKCD wiki](http://wiki.xkcd.com/), which is very helpful for some tricky comics like [XKCD geohashing](http://wiki.xkcd.com/geohashing/Main_Page)

Comment: One way to prevent this would be to escape any special chars before using it in the query. Another way would be to use prepared statements or make sure that you are executing one, and only one, query at a time.

Comment: I believe this link must be recorded here: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Its an SQL Injection. They finish the first statement then run a second one which deletes the table.

Comment: https://beta.companieshouse.gov.uk/company/10542519 is the registration for a consultancy named ; DROP TABLE "COMPANIES";-- LTD

Comment: The comic is slightly grating because you shouldn't *sanitize* database inputs, you should **parametrize** them so it doesn't matter *what* they are. Sanitzers may have bugs. Parametrized queries sidestep the whole issue.

Comment: Is it just me or is someone asking for help in the [title of the question](https://imgur.com/a/0vQ6eVA)?

Answer (score 1203, accepted):

**It drops the students table.**

The original code in the school's program probably looks something like

```
q = "INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('" + FNMName.Text + "', '" + LName.Text + "')";
```

This is the naive way to add text input into a query, and is *very bad*, as you will see.

After the values from the first name, middle name textbox *FNMName.Text* (which is `Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --`) and the last name textbox *LName.Text* (let's call it `Derper`) are concatenated with the rest of the query, the result is now actually *two queries* separated by the [statement terminator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Language_elements) (semicolon).  The second query has been **injected** into the first.  When the code executes this query against the database, it will look like this

```
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; --', 'Derper')
```

which, in plain English, roughly translates to the two queries:

> Add a new record to the Students table with a Name value of 'Robert'

and

> Delete the Students table

Everything past the second query is [marked as a comment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181627.aspx):  `--', 'Derper')`

The `'` in the student's name is not a comment, it's the closing [string delimiter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx).  Since the student's name is a string, it's needed syntactically to complete the hypothetical query.  Injection attacks only work *when the SQL query they inject results in valid SQL*.

<sup><sup>Edited ***again*** as per [dan04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/287586/dan04)'s astute comment</sup></sup>

Comment: Mmm, the WHERE with parentheses around the arguments is rather unusual, but at least it avoids a syntax error... :-)

Comment: @PhiLho: If the original statement were an `INSERT`, then the parenthesis would make more sense.  It would also explain why the database connection isn't in read-only mode.

Comment: As @dan04 explains, the parenthesis makes more sense with an `INSERT`. Thinking backwards, the `SELECT` would not run anyway as the Insert of the Little Bobby Tables in the table would have already dropped the table.

Comment: Actually, in this example the first query ("add a new record...") will fail because `Students` expects more than just the one column (the original/correct statement provided two columns).  That said, the presence of the second column is helpful to show why commenting is required; and since one cannot change Bobby's name, it's probably best leaving as-is with little more than this observation as a footnote.

Comment: It would be syntactically correct if the FirstName were the *last* column in the table, though.

Comment: @dan04 I am kinda old, but I guess they like student's last names now (in the day, students only had first names, teachers only last names).  Fixed, yet again.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Robert''`?

Comment: Can you pass two queries in one statement. The comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1#comment16051205_60174 says you cannot.

Comment: @TejasRamdas you can in mssql

Comment: Bobby's last name - or at least his mother's, is **Roberts**, per [Explain XKCD](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom).  I'm not sure that correcting that would improve the answer clarity, though.

Comment: This example of SQL injection is mentioned in Python SQLite3 library doc page. I try to test this out in python code, but got warning:
"sqlite3.Warning: You can only execute one statement at a time."
Are they already fixed this vulnerability?

Comment: @filler36 allowing one or more statement in a single execution is a choice, not a vulnerability. The vulnerability here is in how the outside-world string is put inside the SQL statement. Rather, here I would expect the surname to be a not nullable column, so that the insert would fail because now you are inserting one less column than needed.

Answer (score 671):

Let's say the name was used in a variable, `$Name`.  You then run this query:

```
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ( '$Name' )
```

The code is mistakenly placing anything the user supplied as the variable. You wanted the SQL to be:

> INSERT INTO Students VALUES ( '<kbd>Robert Tables</kbd>` )

But a clever user can supply whatever they want:

> INSERT INTO Students VALUES ( '<kbd>Robert'); DROP TABLE Students; --</kbd>' )

What you get is:

```
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ( 'Robert' );  DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --' )
```

The `--` only comments the remainder of the line.

Comment: This is much better then the highest voted, because it explains the closing parenthesis.

Comment: By the way, there is no way for the school director in the comics to be aware or the XSS since the student table is deleted, he can't know who has done this.

Comment: @xryl669 Logs are very helpful in situations like this... Sometimes all queries are logged, and sometimes other logged info can help you deduce culprit.

Answer (score 175):

As everyone else has pointed out already, the `');` closes the original statement and then a second statement follows. Most frameworks, including languages like PHP, have default security settings by now that don't allow multiple statements in one SQL string. In PHP, for example, you can only run multiple statements in one SQL string by using the `mysqli_multi_query` function.

You can, however, manipulate an existing SQL statement via SQL injection without having to add a second statement. Let's say you have a login system which checks a username and a password with this simple select:

```
$query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $_REQUEST['user'] . "' and (password='".$_REQUEST['pass']."')";
$result=mysql_query($query);
```

If you provide `peter` as the username and `secret` as the password, the resulting SQL string would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='peter' and (password='secret')
```

Everything's fine. Now imagine you provide this string as the password:

```
' OR '1'='1
```

Then the resulting SQL string would be this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='peter' and (password='' OR '1'='1')
```

That would enable you to log in to any account without knowing the password. So you don't need to be able to use two statements in order to use SQL injection, although you can do more destructive things if you are able to supply multiple statements.

Answer (score 73):

No, `'` isn't a comment in SQL, but a delimiter.

Mom supposed the database programmer made a request looking like:

```
INSERT INTO 'students' ('first_name', 'last_name') VALUES ('$firstName', '$lastName');
```

(for example) to add the new student, where the `$xxx` variable contents was taken directly out of an HTML form, without checking format nor escaping special characters.

So if `$firstName` contains `Robert'); DROP TABLE students; --` the database program will execute the following request directly on the DB:

```
INSERT INTO 'students' ('first_name', 'last_name') VALUES ('Robert'); DROP TABLE students; --', 'XKCD');
```

ie. it will terminate early the insert statement, execute whatever malicious code the cracker wants, then comment out whatever remainder of code there might be.

Mmm, I am too slow, I see already 8 answers before mine in the orange band... :-) A popular topic, it seems.

Answer (score 42):

### TL;DR

```sql
-- The application accepts input, in this case 'Nancy', without attempting to
-- sanitize the input, such as by escaping special characters
school=> INSERT INTO students VALUES ('Nancy');
INSERT 0 1

-- SQL injection occurs when input into a database command is manipulated to
-- cause the database server to execute arbitrary SQL
school=> INSERT INTO students VALUES ('Robert'); DROP TABLE students; --');
INSERT 0 1
DROP TABLE

-- The student records are now gone - it could have been even worse!
school=> SELECT * FROM students;
ERROR:  relation "students" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM students;
                      ^
```

---

#### This drops (deletes) the student table.

(*All code examples in this answer were run on a PostgreSQL 9.1.2 database server.*)

To make it clear what's happening, let's try this with a simple table containing only the name field and add a single row:

```sql
school=> CREATE TABLE students (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY);
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "students_pkey" for table "students"
CREATE TABLE
school=> INSERT INTO students VALUES ('John');
INSERT 0 1
```

Let's assume the application uses the following SQL to insert data into the table:

```sql
INSERT INTO students VALUES ('foobar');
```

Replace `foobar` with the actual name of the student. A normal insert operation would look like this:

```sql
--                            Input:   Nancy
school=> INSERT INTO students VALUES ('Nancy');
INSERT 0 1
```

When we query the table, we get this:

```sql
school=> SELECT * FROM students;
 name
-------
 John
 Nancy
(2 rows)
```

What happens when we insert Little Bobby Tables's name into the table?

```sql
--                            Input:   Robert'); DROP TABLE students; --
school=> INSERT INTO students VALUES ('Robert'); DROP TABLE students; --');
INSERT 0 1
DROP TABLE
```

The SQL injection here is the result of the name of the student terminating the statement and including a separate `DROP TABLE` command; the two dashes at the end of the input are intended to comment out any leftover code that would otherwise cause an error. The last line of the output confirms that the database server has dropped the table.

It's important to notice that during the `INSERT` operation the application isn't checking the input for any special characters, and is therefore allowing arbitrary input to be entered into the SQL command. This means that a malicious user can insert, into a field normally intended for user input, special symbols such as quotes along with arbitrary SQL code to cause the database system to execute it, hence [SQL *injection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

The result?

```sql
school=> SELECT * FROM students;
ERROR:  relation "students" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM students;
                      ^
```

SQL injection is the database equivalent of a remote [arbitrary code execution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary_code_execution) vulnerability in an operating system or application.  The potential impact of a successful SQL injection attack cannot be underestimated--depending on the database system and application configuration, it can be used by an attacker to cause data loss (as in this case), gain unauthorized access to data, or even execute arbitrary code on the host machine itself.

As noted by the XKCD comic, one way of protecting against SQL injection attacks is to sanitize database inputs, such as by escaping special characters, so that they cannot modify the underlying SQL command and therefore cannot cause execution of arbitrary SQL code. This can be done at the application level, and some implementations of parameterized queries operate by sanitizing input.

However, sanitizing inputs at the application level may not stop more advanced SQL injection techniques. For example, [there are ways to circumvent the `mysql_real_escape_string` PHP function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string). For added protection, many database systems support [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement). If properly implemented in the backend, prepared statements can make SQL injection impossible by treating data inputs as semantically separate from the rest of the command.

Comment: SqlParameters are **not sanitized**.They are just interpreted as data only, and never interpreted as code. This is the correct way to do things, keep data and code separate

Answer (score 32):

Say you naively wrote a student creation method like this:

```
void createStudent(String name) {
    database.execute("INSERT INTO students (name) VALUES ('" + name + "')");
}
```

And someone enters the name `Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --`

What gets run on the database is this query:

```
INSERT INTO students (name) VALUES ('Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS --')
```

The semicolon ends the insert command and starts another; the -- comments out the rest of the line. The DROP TABLE command is executed...

This is why bind parameters are a good thing.

Answer (score 30):

A single quote is the start and end of a string. A semicolon is the end of a statement. So if they were doing a select like this:

```
Select *
From Students
Where (Name = '<NameGetsInsertedHere>')
```

The SQL would become:

```
Select *
From Students
Where (Name = 'Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --')
--             ^-------------------------------^
```

On some systems, the `select` would get ran first followed by the `drop` statement! The message is: DONT EMBED VALUES INTO YOUR SQL. Instead use parameters!

Answer (score 21):

The `');` ends the query, it doesn't start a comment. Then it drops the students table and comments the rest of the query that was supposed to be executed.

Answer (score 21):

In this case, `'` is not a comment character.  It's used to delimit string literals.  The comic artist is banking on the idea that the school in question has dynamic sql somewhere that looks something like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Students` (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ('" . $fname . "', '" . $lname . "')";
```

So now the `'` character ends the string literal before the programmer was expecting it.  Combined with the `;` character to end the statement, an attacker can now add (inject) whatever sql they want.  The `--` comment at the end is to make sure any remaining sql in the original statement does not prevent the query from compiling on the server.

FWIW, I also think the comic in question has an important detail wrong: if you ***sanitize*** your database inputs, as the comic suggests, you're still doing it wrong. Instead, you should think in terms of ***quarantining*** your database inputs, and the correct way to do this is via parameterized queries/prepared statements.

Answer (score 19):

The `'` character in SQL is used  for string constants. In this case it is used for ending the string constant and not for comment.

Answer (score 19):

The writer of the database probably did a

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE (STUDENT_NAME = '" + student_name + "') AND other stuff";
execute(sql);
```

If student_name is the one given, that does the selection with the name "Robert" and then drops the table.  The "-- " part changes the rest of the given query into a comment.

Comment: It was my first thought, but you get a syntax error with the trailing closing parenthesis, no?

Comment: That's why there is a -- at the end, indicating the remaining text is a comment and should be ignored.

Answer (score 9):

This is how it works:
Lets suppose the administrator is looking for records of student

```
Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --
```

Since the admin account has high privileges deleting the table from this account is possible.

The code to retrieve user name from request is

Now the query would be something like this (to search the student table)

```
String query="Select * from student where username='"+student_name+"'";

statement.executeQuery(query); //Rest of the code follows
```

The resultant query becomes

```
Select * from student where username='Robert'); DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --
```

Since the user input is not sanitized, The above query has is manipulated into 2 parts

```
Select * from student where username='Robert'); 

DROP TABLE STUDENTS; --
```

The double dash (--) will just comment out remaining part of the query.

This is dangerous as it can nullify password authentication, if present

The first one will do the normal search.

The second one will drop the table student if the account has sufficient privileges (Generally the school admin account will run such query and will have the privileges talked about above).

Comment: ```SELECT* FROM sutdents ...``` - you forgot an "s". This is what you dropping. ```DROP TABLE STUDENTS;```

Answer (score 7):

## You don't need to input form data to make SQL injection.

No one pointed this out before so through I might alert some of you.

Mostly we will try to patch forms input. But this is not the only place where you can get attacked with SQL injection. You can do very simple attack with URL which send data through GET request;
Consider the fallowing example:

```
<a href="/show?id=1">show something</a>
```

Your url would look 
http://yoursite.com/show?id=1

Now someone could try something like this

```
http://yoursite.com/show?id=1;TRUNCATE table_name
```

Try to replace table_name with the real table name. If he get your table name right they would empty your table! **(It is very easy to brut force this URL with simple script)**

Your query would look something like this...

```
"SELECT * FROM page WHERE id = 4;TRUNCATE page"
```

#### Example of PHP vulnerable code using PDO:

```
<?php
...
$id = $_GET['id'];

$pdo = new PDO($database_dsn, $database_user, $database_pass);
$query = "SELECT * FROM page WHERE id = {$id}";
$stmt = $pdo->query($query);
$data = $stmt->fetch(); 
/************* You have lost your data!!! :( *************/
...
```

#### Solution - use PDO prepare() & bindParam() methods:

```
<?php
...
$id = $_GET['id'];

$query = 'SELECT * FROM page WHERE id = :idVal';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam('idVal', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetch();
/************* Your data is safe! :) *************/
...
```

Comment: Could this vulnerability be solved with $id = str_replace(';' , '', $_GET['id']); ??